# if number in dataframe column 1 is x and if column 2 is y return result

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

run code below:

Looking at col A if at any time a number occurs (eg row 5 to 9) and the corresponding 'close' on the row is higher than the highest close in the previous set of numbers (in this case the previous set of numbers is between row 14 and 17 and the highest number in this set was row 15 with 8373) than a 'GOOD' occurs.  A 'GOOD' can only occur once in a set.

I have provided col B as a template of what it should look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def update():

  df = pd.DataFrame()

  df['close'] = (7980,7996,8155,8363,8283,8303,8266,8582,8586,8179,8206,7854,8145,8152,8240,8373,8319,8298,8048,8218,8188,8055,8432,8537,9682,10021,9985,10169,10272,10152,10196,10270,10306,10355,10369,10420,10154,10096,10307,10400,10484,10311,10574,10586,10618,10384,9768,9594,9580,9490,9712,10167,10361,10137,10150,10402,10112,10135,10772,10927)

  df['A'] = ('','','','','',5,4,3,2,1,'','','','',4,3,2,1,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','',4,3,2,1,'','','','','','',5,4,3,2,1,'','','','','',2,1,'','','','','','',)

  df['B'] = ('','','','','','','','','GOOD','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','GOOD','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',)

  print(df)

update()
```

Comment: Can you please describe more where should the GOOD be positioned?

Comment: when there is any number in column A (for instance row 5 to 9) AND the corresponding 'close' is a higher number than any close in the previous GROUP of numbers in column A (so row 5 to 9 is to be checked against the highest number between rows 14 and 17)

Comment: The highest number in row 14 to 17 is 8373. So when the next group of numbers start to occur (i.e row 5 to 9) it is looking if the close is higher than 8373.  if it does a 'GOOD' is printed